# Print only full paths of files and directories using `ls`

Tags: linux, bash

For a given directory the request is to print the full paths of files and directories

e.g. for

```
      /a/b/c/
            file1
            file2
            dir1/
```

The command should show

```
/a/b/c/file1
/a/b/c/file2
/a/b/c/dir1
```

The form of it would be either

```
ls -<something> .
```

or

```
ls -<something> /a/b/c
```

I would think that would be trivial to achieve but did not find it having perused all of the `ls` switches. Did I miss it - or should something else like `find` be used?

Comment: [linux - How to get full path of a file? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file)

Comment: @DavidPostill fair enough: but it's not on the most appropriate site ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` can give you the desired format almost by default. It's [obliged](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) to use pathnames that start with the path you provided, so provide `/a/b/c`:

```
find /a/b/c
```

which is equivalent to

```
find /a/b/c -print
```

There are two problems here:

1. `/a/b/c` will also be printed.
2. `find` works recursively. It's not clear if `dir1` in your example is empty or its content is omitted. You may or may not want recursion.

The problem can be solved by `-mindepth 1` and `-maxdepth 1` respectively, if your `find` supports them:

```
find /a/b/c -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
```

These options are not required by POSIX. With POSIX `find` you can suppress printing `/a/b/c` with `! -path /a/b/c`; and you can "emulate" `-maxdepth 1` by following this: [*Limit POSIX find to specific depth?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/108618)

This is a POSIX solution:

```
find /a/b/c ! -path /a/b/c -prune
```

Sole `/a/b/c` will not pass the `! -path` test. Anything that passes will be pruned, so the tool will not descend deeper.

Providing the starting path as `/a/b/c/` (note the trailing slash) requires you to use `! -path /a/b/c/` (also with a trailing slash) because `find` is obliged to refer to its starting path exactly as it was provided. `/a/b/c/` does not match `/a/b/c` and vice versa. Remember `-path` treats is argument as a pattern, this is important if your starting path contains literal `*` or other characters used in [*Pattern Matching Notation*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13).

---

You requested specific format, so maybe you want to parse the output. In this case `find` is your tool and `ls` definitely is not, because [you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If your `find` is GNU `find`, check the `UNUSUAL FILENAMES` section in `man 1 find`. Consider `-print0`.

In a comment you were given a link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5265702/10765659). Many solutions there require supplying a path to some tool (like `readlink`). If the original path comes from `ls`, it's already an act of "parsing `ls`" – not recommended.

However tools from this other question may be useful in your case to turn a relative path like `./c` or `c` to full path like `/a/b/c`. Then you provide the full path to `find`.